# Upload file via URL

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, macos

I'm a recent Mac convert. In Windows when I wanted to upload a file to a website I could do this (see the URL in the File Name text field):

[image: Windows' version]

However there's no way to do that in the upload dialog for Mac (notice, no text field to even do this in):

[image: Apple's version]

At least not that I'm aware of. This means that I have to actually download the file and then upload it using the dialog. I realize that the window's method actually downloads the file to a temp directory and then uploads it, but I don't have to think about that ("it just works").

Which is why I'm asking this question. Is there any application or any settings I could change to make this possible on my MacBook Pro? I'm running OS X 10.8.2 and my preferred browser is Chrome.

P.S. I realize that on this site there's a way to link with a URL, but on sites like Facebook and Google+ there is no option for that. :) Don't address this issue, that's not my question :) Thanks!

Comment: Just found this similar question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/48693/36639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is today, there is no way you can do this through the Finder file upload dialog. I also can't find any Chrome Extensions that can do this, but making one shouldn't be too hard. It's times like these you want to be able to do it yourself, right?

The conclusion that made in 2002 [here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=592715&postcount=18) is still relevant:

> "Macs cannot do some things using the same techniques as a Windows-based system can."